# Cygwin shadow.h not found

Tags: c, cygwin

I am trying to compile a program in Cygwin and it requires shadow.h in one of the source files, which is missing in the /usr/include path. How do I add shadow support in Cygwin ? any packages to install ?

In CentOS, just installing gcc and glibc provided the shadow.h header file. what are the equivalent packages that I need to install in Cygwin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shadow.h is to define the type struct spwd, and it is a part of Gnulib.Your compilation is not getting support of this lib.

There should be a libshadow.a in /usr/lib and you need to include it during build as follows

```
gcc program.c -o program -lshadow
```

for better understanding you can [look here also](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-8.html).

```
Edited Later:
```

I just got to know there is some issues in porting of shadow.h and this problem covers cygwin too.Please [refer here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/shadow_002eh.html).

Comment: Is there a workaround for these portability problems for cygwin ? I am using autoconf and make to compile the project.

Comment: @sabs6488 i do not have any idea about it.Any workaround will call /usr/lib/shadow and there it won't get support from Gnulib on cygwin for shadow.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.. Will look for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is none currently, so this isn't going to work until someone contributes those APIs to Cygwin.